# Revert a jQuery function, from xml to html and back

Tags: jquery, html, xml, revert

I have to worked with xml files in jQuery, and jQuery can't work with `<`, `>`, `&` and other codes. I found this code on google:

```
function escapeHtml(text) {
    var map = {
        '&': '&amp;',
        '<': '&lt;',
        '>': '&gt;',
    };
    return text.replace(/[&<>]/g, function(m) {
        return map[m];
    });
}
```

It works, but now I need to export this file, and it returns with `&lt;` `&gt;` as text, is there a way to revert this back?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan replace function isnt working with < >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do it like this by swapping the keys and objects and using `Object.keys`

```
function toHTML(text) {
    var map = {
        '&amp;': '&',
        '&lt;': '<',
        '&gt;': '>',
    };
    return text.replace(new RegExp(Object.keys(map).join("|"),"g"), function(m) {
        return map[m];
    });
}
```